# Is there a method for removing whitespace characters from a string?

Tags: c#, .net, string, standard-library

Is there a `string` class member function (or something else) for removing all spaces from a string? Something like Python's `str.strip()` ?

Comment: Just space characters or all whitespace?  Python's `strip` removes whitespace by default

Comment: I want to remove all whitespaces.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You could simply do:

```
myString = myString.Replace(" ", "");
```

If you want to remove *all* white space characters you could use Linq, even if the syntax is not very appealing for this use case:

```
myString = new string(myString.Where(c => !char.IsWhiteSpace(c)).ToArray());
```

Answer (score 19):

[String.Trim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trim.aspx) method removes trailing and leading white spaces. It is the functional equivalent of Python's strip method.

Comment: Sorry, my question was a bit unclear. I intended to remove all spaces from a string. Still you deserve a +1.

Answer (score 8):

LINQ feels like overkill here, converting a string to a list, filtering the list, then turning it back onto a string. For removal of all white space, I would go for a regular expression. `Regex.Replace(s, @"\s", "")`. This is a common idiom and has probably been optimized.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to remove the spaces that prepend the string or at itt's end, you might want to have a look at TrimStart() and TrimEnd() and Trim().

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking to replace **all** whitespace in a string (not just leading and trailing whitespace) based on .NET's determination of what's whitespace or not, you could use a pretty simple LINQ query to make it work.

```
string whitespaceStripped = new string((from char c in someString
                                        where !char.IsWhiteSpace(c)
                                        select c).ToArray());
```

Comment: It should be noted that this one is different from all the other examples in that it removes all whitespace, not just spaces.  This will also remove tabs, newlines, vertical tabs, probably other chars as well.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Trim.

```
String a = "blabla ";
var b = a.Trim(); // or TrimEnd or TrimStart
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, [`String.Trim()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trim.aspx).

```
var result = "   a b    ".Trim();
```

gives `"a b"` in `result`. By default all whitespace is trimmed. If you want to remove only space you need to type

```
var result = "   a b    ".Trim(' ');
```

If you want to remove **all** spaces in a string you can use [`string.Replace()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace.aspx).

```
var result = "   a b    ".Replace(" ", "");
```

gives `"ab"` in `result`. But that is not equivalent to `str.strip()` in Python.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about Python...

IF the `str.strip()` just removes whitespace at the start and the end then you could use `str = str.Trim()` in .NET... otherwise you could just `str = str.Replace ( " ", "")` for removing all spaces.

IF it removes all whitespace then use

```
str = (from c in str where !char.IsWhiteSpace(c) select c).ToString()
```

Comment: `str = (from c in str where !char.IsWhiteSpace(c) select c).ToString()` doesn't work. It doesn't output what you think it does.

Answer (score 1):

There are many diffrent ways, some faster then others:

```
public static string StripTabsAndNewlines(this string s) {

    //string builder (fast)
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++) {
        if ( !  Char.IsWhiteSpace(s[i])) {
            sb.Append();
        }
    }
    return sb.tostring();

    //linq (faster ?)
    return new string(input.ToCharArray().Where(c => !Char.IsWhiteSpace(c)).ToArray());

    //regex (slow)
    return Regex.Replace(s, @"\s+", "")

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use

```
 StringVariable.Replace(" ","")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised no one mentioned this:

`String.Join("", " all  manner\tof\ndifferent\twhite spaces!\n".Split())`

`string.Split` by default splits along the characters that are `char.IsWhiteSpace` so this is a very similar solution to filtering those characters out by the direct use of `char.IsWhiteSpace` and it's a one-liner that works in pre-LINQ environments as well.

Answer (score -2):

Strip spaces? Strip whitespaces? Why should it matter? It only matters if we're searching for an existing implementation, but let's not forget how fun it is to *program* the solution rather than search MSDN (boring).

You should be able to strip any chars from any string by using 1 of the 2 functions below.

You can remove any chars like this

```
static string RemoveCharsFromString(string textChars, string removeChars)
{
    string tempResult = "";
    foreach (char c in textChars)
    {
        if (!removeChars.Contains(c))
        {
            tempResult = tempResult + c;
        }
    }
    return tempResult;
}
```

or you can enforce a character set (so to speak) like this

```
static string EnforceCharLimitation(string textChars, string allowChars)
{
    string tempResult = "";
    foreach (char c in textChars)
    {
        if (allowChars.Contains(c))
        {
            tempResult = tempResult + c;
        }
    }

    return tempResult;
}
```

Comment: It does matter because this solution is extremely slow and inefficient  compared to the standard existing techniques and implementations...

Comment: Are we back in the 1970s with <10MHz CPUs again? How will you remain employable if MSDN ever goes offline? I suppose you've committed MSDN to memory! Wait a few more months and we'll see if the MS-"standard" is still the same! (:-D) BTW, the fastest solution is proper input-validation and data-structure design in the first place, not string manipulation to compensate for the habits of those who are enthralled by high-level functions that promise the world! It's probably a generational thing. I like to build it, you prefer to use it. The OP didn't indicate any emphasis on speed. (;-D)

Comment: No, but if one of my devs spent hours writing a poor solution such as yours vs googling for an existing simple, fast & well implemented solution I would question their employment. Above you can see my answer that solves question in 3 different ways, all far more efficient then your proposed solution. In yours on each character in the input string you enumerate the allowedChars str (use a hashset<char> for  O(1) instead of O(n) lookup). Not only that for each replacement you create a new string instead of a pre allocated array or StringBuilder. And you don't actually answer the question.

Comment: I can discover electricity. You can switch on a light bulb (and play around with a variable resistor)! (;-D)

Comment: I don't entirely agree with @Sam here, but I think claiming his solution to be inefficient because O(n) vs O(1) is also unfair. In this exact case, the allowed characters are going to be small, and so that O(n) case converges on the real cost of the O(1) case. Hash->index has a cost. If we compared the cycles of his solution versus the hashset solution, the O(n) is going to outperform the O(1) in sufficiently small cases. And given that this cost is done per character in a string which COULD be large, this expense is multiplicative and his solution could end up meaningfully more performant.

Comment: If I was going to critique the performance, it'd be because of 'tempResult = tempResult + c'. A StringBuffer with a preallocated textChars.Length size would give a substantial performance improvement in cases where textChars is large.