# How can I remove a single leading space while replacing whitespace?

Tags: c#, .net, str-replace

I have a basic string:

```
string myString = " programming  -  lang - cSharp c";
```

I would like to:

- Remove the space from the beginning of the string.
- Replace additional spaces with `-`:

  - Only, ***if*** there isn't a dash there already.
  - If dashes are present between whitespace, the whitespace surrounding that dash should be removed.

---

Expected Output

> programming-lang-csharp-c

Comment: `string.Replace`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove whitespace before or after a character with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48457758/remove-whitespace-before-or-after-a-character-with-regex) and [Is there a method for removing whitespace characters from a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7383254/is-there-a-method-for-removing-whitespace-characters-from-a-string)

Comment: Replace space-dash and dash-space with a dash?

Comment: Regex or `myString = myString.Replace(" - ", "-");` ?

Comment: Check my answer and comment for idea and logic . You can make it work that way

Answer (score 1):

```
String yourstring = ' programming - lang - csharp c'

yourstring = yourstring.replace("  -  ","-");
yourstring = yourstring.trim()
yourstring = yourstring.replace(" ", "-");
```

Edit: `yourstring.trim()` would only remove the whitespaces at the beginning and the end of the string, so you have to use `yourstring.replace(" ", "-")` to replace all other whitespaces in the string

Comment: Here just first replace your space and dash with just one dash then with trim function remove extra space

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```cs
public static string ToKebabCase( string s ) {
  return rxWhitespaceOrHyphen
         .Replace( s , "-" )
         .Trim('-')
         .ToLower()
         ;
}
// Regular expression matching a sequence of whitespace or hyphen characters
private static Regex rxWhitespaceOrHyphen = new Regex( @"(\s|-)+" );
```

Another way to do it is to extract the "interesting" bits and glue them back together:

```cs
public static string ToKebabCase( string s ) {
  return String.Join( '-',
    rxWhitespaceOrHyphen.Split( s, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries )
  );
}
// Regular expression matching a sequence of characters other than whitespace or hyphen
private static Regex rxWhitespaceOrHyphen = new Regex( @"(\s|-)+" );
```